# model.predict in tensorflow is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing this code to predict the final answer but I am not getting it.

Here is my code
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow import keras

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.array([-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([-3.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0], dtype=float)

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500)

print(model.predict([10.0]))
```

And I am getting the error like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dwt3.png)

Comment: Please format code using triple backticks and add all code directly to the question (no images).

Answer (score 0):

The input shape should be (1,) not [1].

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,))])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in the first layer where you mention `input_shape`. When you have one dimension as in your case, comma (`,`) is necessary. Under the hood, model will add batch dimension. However, if you have two or more dimensions in your `input_shape` you don't need comma `,` in the end. So change the following line

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,))])
```

Here is your updated full code that works for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,))]) 
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float) 
ys = np.array([-3.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0], dtype=float)

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=50)

print(model.predict([10.0]))
```